# Running a Java application from RAM

Tags: java, file, memory, jvm

Typically, Java application runs with the start argument - path to .jar or .class .

But how to run a Java if my file in memory?

If these methods do not exist, can possibly compile Java with the argument

```
byte[] FileFromMemory
```

or

```
bufferedreader FileFromMemory
```

I'm trying to run from С++ application

Comment: Do you just have the source of the Java file, or the actual byte code of a class file?

Comment: Both: source and byte code of a class file. And i have a bit experience with using class loader for class detection: if(classloader.getResource("my.class") != null)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a customer classloader to do this or load the class into an existing class loader using reflection.  Both approaches are considered very advanced topics so I would reconsider this unless you have many years of Java experience.

The simplest solution is to write the file to disk e.g. a Ramdisk like `tmpfs`  This is a simpler (if less efficient) way to do this.

Comment: (+1) for the advice to reconsider.

Comment: Ramdisk does not suit me. Java file stored on disk. But I need to store it and transmit encrypted, and decrypt before the launch. And launch without save decrypted on disk.

Comment: In that case a Custom ClassLoader is what you need.  You need to override findClass to perform the lookup and define the classes as required.  Look at the source for URLClassLoader as an example.

Answer (score 2):

If your code (`.jar`/`.class`) resides in RAM and not on a file system, you'll need to provide your own [class loader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).